# FAB not visible when fragment opens on default

Tags: android

I have a fragment which opens on click of one of the bottom nav icons. In that fragment I have a RecyclerView and a FAB. There are 4 fragments in total which open on click of each of the 4 icons in Bottom Nav.

I want the fragment with recyclerView and FAB to open on default when the activity is launched.

Problem - The FAB button is not visible when the fragment opens on default when app is launched but if I click on the bottom Nav icon, FAB button appears in the fragment. What could be the issue?

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_chat_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/edit_fab_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:background="@color/fab_button_bg"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/fab_button_bg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/edit"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/pen"
        android:tint="@color/login_text_color"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_button_bg"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="12dp"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

HomeActivity.kt

```
package com.kunalrai.buzz.ui.home

import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telecom.InCallService
import android.text.Html
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import com.kunalrai.buzz.R


class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var bottom_nav: BottomNavigationView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        bottom_nav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav)
        bottom_nav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

        bottom_nav.menu.getItem(2).isChecked = true
    }

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.navigation_chat -> {
                val fragment = HomeFragment()
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment, fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
                    .commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.navigation_settings -> {
                val fragment = SettingsFragment()
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment, fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
                    .commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.navigation_calls -> {
                val fragment = CallsFragment()
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment, fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
                    .commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.navigation_video_call -> {
                val fragment = VideoCallFragment()
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment, fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
                    .commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.getItemId()) {
            R.id.notification ->         //add the function to perform here
                return true
            R.id.search_chat ->         //add the function to perform here
                return true
            R.id.tick ->         //add the function to perform here
                return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

}
```

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/button_text_color"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/button_text_color"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/button_text_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/button_text_color"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:elevation="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/camera" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

check the mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener and

```
bottom_nav.menu.getItem(2).isChecked = true
```

is for default fragment when HomeActivity opens

Comment: Please post the code of your fragment layout and fragment, so we can better help you

Comment: @A.Patrik added

Comment: I see `R.id.flFragment` in your code, where is this layout in xml?

Comment: That is activity_home.xml. added the code